# resizing images that I have loaded from public flicker feed

Tags: actionscript-3, flicker

I'm trying to resize photos that I have loaded from the public photo feed on flicker.  I'm able to get the photos and view them with add child, but if I try to resize them they will not load and I am not getting any errors.

Here is the code:

```
    public function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
        urlloader=new URLLoader();
        var req=new URLRequest("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne" );
        var urlvars:URLVariables=new URLVariables();
        urlvars.format ="rss_200";
        urlvars.tags="cat";
        req.data=urlvars;
        urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoaded);
        urlloader.load(req);
    }
    public function onXMLLoaded(e:Event):void{
        trace(urlloader.data);
        var xml:XML = new XML (urlloader.data);
        urls=[];
        var mediaNS:Namespace=new Namespace("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" );
        for(var i:int =0; i<xml.channel.item.length();i++){
            urls.push(xml.channel.item[i].mediaNS::content.@url);
        }
        //trace(xml.channel.item[i].guid.height.mediaNS::content.@url);
        loadPhotos();
        trace(urls.length);
        trace(urls[1]);

    }
    public function loadPhotos():void{
        var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
        var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest(urls[1]);
        ldr.load(req);
        trace("image loaded");
        addChild(ldr);
        ldr.width=200;
        ldr.height=200;


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resize the images *after* they have finished loading. At the moment, you're trying to resize images that aren't loaded yet (and have a width / height of 0,0).

`Event.COMPLETE` can help you out with this, sample:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e6420234b202a900e8d57d4e714aa184?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

loader.load(request);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, resizeImage);

function resizeImage(e:Event):void
{
    loader.width = 500;
    loader.height = 400;

    addChild(loader);
}
```